# Loitering Classes and functions in Actionscript application

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection, flash-builder

I'm profiling my application (using Flash Develop Profiler)and most of the space is taken by loitering classes/function . Most of them I've taken care of. But there are two types of loitering objects that I cannot figure out.

- **Xmovieclip frame 21** . Xmovieclip is an movieclip exported for actionscript. On frame 21 it has an action stop() . The swf is loaded and an instance of this movieclip is made.
- This one is another loitering function

  ```
  String:$cinit()
  [new class]()
  global$init:global$init()
  ```
- and finally this function

  ```
  private function onAllDefinitionsLoadComplete(e:LoaderEvent):void
  {

      dispatchEvent(new AssetManagerEvent(AssetManagerEvent.ASSET_DEFINITION_LOADED));
  }
  ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler generates a fair bit of it's own wrapper ActionScript for intrinsic classes and methods etc, so this is nothing to be concerned about.

Try compiling and profiling a blank SWF and you will see all the overhead that comes along with your app.

There is no reason to try and tidy these up, as they are core to any Flash application. I would just worry about objects you create.